# Does someone pronounce "cover" to be "gover"?

Tags: pronunciation

> And nothing covers me quite enough.

I heard someone read "covers" to be "govers".
I know the pronunciation of "screen" could be "sgreen". But, the "cover" to "gover" sounds a little stange.

Answer (score 1):

What's *govers?* The pronunciation of *screen* could be *sgreen?* Which English you are talking about! :)

You may add a little research on this and edit the question. But I'm writing this answer because there is something worth mentioning.

Often, the last word's pronunciation is carried onto the next word. And here, **that** seems to be the case. The previous word in the sentence ends with 'g' that could have extended and merged with the next word starting with 'k'.

That speech could have the speaker speaking *'Nothinggcovers'* fast that made you hear 'govers.' There's no such word; at least not in my knowledge.

Comment: Yes, this exactly.   When talking quickly in pretty much any language, the sounds of the different words can blend together.  But when speaking clearly, "c" as in "cover" or "screen" is a hard "k" sound.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, Maulik, old bean. Got to give you a -1 there. Why? Because *screen* **is** pronounced something like *sgreen*!!! (There is no aspiration and no positive VOT on a plosive when preceded by /s/ in a syllable onset. So the consonant there will be indistinguishable for most native English speakers from [g]). But I'll reverse my vote if you edit your post!

Comment: @Araucaria that was shocking to me and I checked all dictionaries' pronunciation and nowhere (even in the brackets where they 'write' pronunciation) I found 'g.' I'd rather stick to my stance than get an upvote! :) I may not fully understand the nuance of plosive and consonant in your comment, but I rather believe in what I carefully **hear** when I click the speaker button on all the dictionaries.

Comment: @MaulikV What you hear is your brain interpreting the sound. It's not up for debate, because it's scientifically *proven*. If you chop the [s] off a word like *screen* and play the rest of the word back to native speakers, the vast majority will confidently tell you it's the word *green*. The reason dictionaries use /k/ there, is because they reckon the *phoneme* is most probably /k/, even if the sound is [g] - but, in fact, there's no way of telling what the phoneme is because there's no way to contrast it. ...

Comment: @MaulikV ... Go up to any native speaker and say *sgreen* and ask them what you said. They'll instantly say *screen* and they won't have found your pronunciation odd in any way!